# How to handle hibernate mapping Column error?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I'm using Java class as an Entity that should be mapped to a sql table.
My problem is that I have one field that I don't want it to be a coulmn, but when running my `.war` -> I get o`rg.hibernate.mapping.Column` error.

Is there a way I can add it without converting it to a Column?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "queue", indexes = {@Index(name = "fileSha1", columnList = "fileSha1"),
    @Index(name = "fileSha256", columnList = "fileSha256"),
    @Index(name = "fileMd5", columnList = "fileMd5")})
public class MyQueue{

 // HERE - I don't want it as a column
protected List<enum> parts_codes = new ArrayList<>();

@Column
protected String Method;

@Column
protected String profileName = "test";


@Column
private String downloadUrl;
```

Comment: it should be annotated somewhat like this @OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="personId")  plz refer http://tadtech.blogspot.in/2007/09/hibernate-association-mappings-in.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `@Transient` annotation the field will be ignored by entity manager.